# Problem with changing point position in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid, auto-increment

i'm trying to make simple "point move" in Python, using autoincrement on specific symbol, but it's not working properly(position stays the same), so I need a little help here

```
import re

while True:
    m=input(str("How robot should move? (use U,D,L,R to move): "))
if not re.match("^[U,D,L,R]*$", m):
    print("WRONG MOVE! USE -> U,D,L,R")
if re.match("^[U,D,L,R]*$", m):
    moves = list(m.split())
    print(moves)

    x = 0
    y = 1
    position = [x, y]

    for U in moves:
        if U == "U":
            y+=y
        print(position)
        break
```

I want to get position change with every symbol in list, so if input will be "U,U,U" y new position will be [0,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
x = list(map(str,input().split(",")))

a = 0
b = 0

for i in x:
    if (i=='U'):
        b+=1
        print(a,b)
    elif (i=='D'):
        b-=1
        print(a,b)
    elif (i=='L'):
        a-=1
        print(a,b)
    elif (i=='R'):
        a+=1
        print(a,b)
    else:
        print("wrong move")
        break;
```